# Integrate SVN with Visual Studio 2003

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, svn, visualsvn

I am trying to find a free tool which is not VisualSVN(I know VisualSVN integrates with Visual Studio 2003/2005/2008/2010....) that will integrate Sub Version/TortoiseSVN with Visual Studio 2003. 
There is also another tool that integrates Visual Studio 2005/2008/2010 with SVN, given in the hyperlink here -> http://garrys-brain.blogspot.ca/2007/07/tortoisesvn-and-visual-studio.html but does not integrate with Visual Studio 2003.

Comment: "which is not VisualSVN"? O_o

Comment: Which is not VisualSVN?

Comment: I've used the Agent SVN plug-in with VC++ 6.0, VS 2005, VS 2008 and VS 2010 so it probably also works with VS 2003. But it is not free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Agent SVN](http://www.zeusedit.com/agent/) is a *MS-SCCI* Subversion plug-in so it should work with VS 2003.

Answer (score 1):

What we did was set up the various TortoiseSVN shell commands as External Tools in VS 2003.  Worked very well.

Comment: Did that then allow you to check in, check out code from Visual Studio 2003 from the VS editor like it does in VisualSVN?

Comment: Yes, up to a point:  using External Tools, you can set up command strings with placeholders for "current file", "current file extension", "current directory", etc.  So we could check in and check out.  The limits were the limits the placeholder behavior put on us.  I don't remember all the details but I'd encourage you to set up Check Out or Check In as an External Tool and see how it behaves from the Solution Explorer, from the middle of a code file, etc.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll be happy to give this a shot. I was wondering what the shell commands are and how we can set up Checkin Checkout from Solution Explorer.

Comment: I can't tell you off-hand what the shell commands are:  this was something we did years ago.  But it wasn't too hard to figure out.  I *think* that if your active window is the Solution Explorer, your "current file" is whatever file you've selected in that window as far as External Tools is concerned.  That allowed us to select a file and then click the menu option we'd set up for "Check In".  But I don't remember exactly.

Comment: Putting TortoiseSVN's commands on Visual Studio toolbar is **not** integration. What about status icons, file operations tracking etc etc?

Comment: @bahrep You're right, of course:  what I suggested isn't full integration.  But there's no harm in offering partial solutions, in case there isn't a full solution available that meets the OP's criteria.